# get sales tax from QBO

Tags: php, quickbooks-online

Referring to https://ipp.developer.intuit.com/0010_Intuit_Partner_Platform/0050_Data_Services/0400_QuickBooks_Online/0500_Supported_Entities_and_Operations, it seems like it is not possible to retrieve salestax object for QBO through Intuit Data Service(IDS).

HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error Date: Thu, 27 Dec 2012 09:46:34 GMT Server: Apache Set-Cookie: qboeuid=10.129.32.5.1356601594381793; path=/; expires=Fri, 27-Dec-13 09:46:34 GMT; domain=.intuit.com Vary: Accept-Encoding Content-Encoding: gzip Content-Length: 190 Connection: close Content-Type: application/xml Internal Server Error500SERVER is the response I'm getting when I try to retrieve salesTaxes.

Is the internal server error coming because of the same reason?

Comment: You are correct - IDS does not support it. See this other topic for related details and confirmation from Intuit: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14130566/is-it-possible-to-select-a-tax-agency-when-creating-an-invoice

Answer (score 2):

The [SalesReceipt](https://ipp.developer.intuit.com/0010_Intuit_Partner_Platform/0050_Data_Services/0400_QuickBooks_Online/SalesReceipt) object has a `TaxAmt` attribute.

Comment: This isn't what he's looking for. He's looking for a list of sales tax rate objects, not a specific tax amount on a specific transaction.