# Is it possible to select a Tax Agency when creating an invoice?

Tags: intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online

Is there anyway to get at my clients Tax Agencies when creating an invoice?

I'm using the C# IPP DevKit against QBO.

I don't see it mentioned in the documentation, however I can't imagine I'll be required to hard code all my clients tax tables into my app as that is silly.

Comment: Contact Intuit developer support.. ?

Comment: Are you looking for tax AGENCY data (e.g. a Vendor in QuickBooks), or tax RATES? Those are two very different types of data, and your question makes it sound as if you're not quite sure which you're looking for...

Comment: This is for QBO btw.  When I'm creating a new invoice I would prefer to select on of the named Tax Rate/Agencies that are set up in: Company->Sales Tax->Add/Edit tax rates and agencies, so my clients can use the Sales Tax Center instead of having all the sales tax showing as "Original Sales Tax" on the invoices and lumping all together.

Comment: and lumping all together in the sales tax center."

Comment: OK, those aren't really "agencies" in terms of the API, those are a list of sales tax rates. So Jarred's answer isn't going to be applicable as it wasn't real clear what you were asking for. See my answer below and a related forum thread link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for (the list of tax rates) is not really what you're asking for (tax agencies).

In any case, this thread answers your question:
https://idnforums.intuit.com/messageview.aspx?catid=87&threadid=18930&enterthread=y

Unfortunately, the answer is:

> In the current SDK or Services V2, this is a limitation that the tax code Id is not retained due to tax model changes. This limitation will be addressed in QBO Service V3.

Thus, what you're trying to do can't be done right now.

Comment: Hahahaha, you got that right! I've been asking for MONTHS now for an update on status... the guy who *was* leading the v3 project is on a different project now and doesn't know anything. The last v3 schema Intuit released was complete and utter crap - littered with problems. Who knows what or when they'll actually release. Ick!

Comment: Did you go to the V3 Webinar on 2/22/2013? If you missed it, there is a recording here: http://ippblog.intuit.com/blog/2013/02/quickbooks-api-v3-webinar-recording.html

Comment: Thanks! After 6 months without an update and 6 months of falling behind schedule, it's about time Intuit communicated *something* to developers.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you are using QuickBooks Online or for Windows.
Either way, the Tax Agency would most likely be a Vendor in the customer's QuickBooks file.

So use the vendor query in the devkit to pull the list of vendor's and you can later use the CDCasOf filter to get the new or modified vendors to keep things up to date.

The supported objects and operations are listed here for future reference.

QBO:[link](https://ipp.developer.intuit.com/0010_Intuit_Partner_Platform/0050_Data_Services/0400_QuickBooks_Online/0500_Supported_Entities_and_Operations)
QBD:[link](https://ipp.developer.intuit.com/0010_Intuit_Partner_Platform/0050_Data_Services/0500_QuickBooks_Windows/0600_Object_Reference)

regards,
Jarred

Comment: Sorry, meant to tag this as QBO.  I'm referring specifically to the rate/agencies set up in the sales tax center.  Now when adding a sales tax to an invoice via ipp, It's getting labeled as "Original Sales Tax" and I would prefer it be labeled with the named agencies.