# SalesTaxQuery QuickBooks Online

Tags: intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online

I am trying to assign a tax class to a Sales Receipt. I am unable to pull the Id of a sales tax code. Here is my code:

`var slList = dataServices.FindAll<SalesTax>(new SalesTax(), 1, 100);`

SalesTaxQuery only exists to QuickBooks Desktop in the Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbd namespace. What is the QuickBooks Online one? How do I pull an IdType?

[image: Sales Tax]

Can I add tax lines:

```
                qboSalesReceiptLine.Taxable = true;
                qboSalesReceiptLine.TaxableSpecified = true;

                //add a tax line
                TaxLine tl = new TaxLine();
                tl.Amount = _Item.PriceInclTax - _Item.PriceExclTax;
                tl.AmountSpecified = true;
                tlList.Add(tl);
            qboSalesReceipt.TaxLine = tlList.ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, Intuit's current APIs do not support what you're trying to do.

You can reference these threads for other people asking the same question, and the official Intuit response, you can see this thread and this SO post:

- https://idnforums.intuit.com/messageview.aspx?catid=87&threadid=18930&enterthread=y
- [Is it possible to select a Tax Agency when creating an invoice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14130566/is-it-possible-to-select-a-tax-agency-when-creating-an-invoice)

Supposedly, Intuit v3 data services will resolve this problem. Unfortunately, Intuit is many months behind on v3 implementation, has only posted a preliminary v3 spec that's riddled with bugs and problems, has never updated and then subsequently pulled their v3 roadmap from the website, and refuses to answer any questions about the status or timeline of v3. Sooooo... I wouldn't get your hopes up about any of that functionality being available anytime soon.

Sorry for the bad news. :-/ Welcome to integration with QuickBooks!

Comment: Keith, can I add tax lines? How do I add the tax without the agency?

Comment: You should still be able to add tax amounts/rates by using the TaxAmt and TaxRate fields - it just won't necessarily be under the right tax location/classification: https://ipp.developer.intuit.com/0010_Intuit_Partner_Platform/0050_Data_Services/0400_QuickBooks_Online/SalesReceipt